# Trying to wrap a jQuery plugin as an Ember component

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to wrap the [Hootsuite Grid](https://github.com/hootsuite/grid) plugin as an Ember component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed } = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  elementId: 'grid',
  classNames: ['grid'],
  tagName: 'ul',
  didInsertElement() {
    var self = this;
    var options = {
      lanes: 5,
      direction: 'horizontal',
      itemSelector: 'li[data-w]',
      widthHeightRatio: 1,
      onChange(changedItems) {
        console.log(this);
      }
    };
    var gridList = this.$().gridList(options);
    this.set('gridList', gridList);
  },
  willDestroyElement() {
    this.get('gridList').stop();
  }
});
```

When I `console.log(this);` I can see that the options are correctly set on the parent object, but not passed to the internal gridList object

[image: Properties in Chrome expor]

Whereas these values seem to be passed to the child object in the test fiddle that I was playing with:

https://jsfiddle.net/evmowy9k/

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ember.run.next(this, function() {
    var gridList = this.$().gridList(options);
    this.set('gridList', gridList);
});
```